# How to ensure Pycharm doesn't display project name at start of terminal prompt?

Tags: terminal, pycharm, zsh, oh-my-zsh

When I initialise a new terminal window in Pycharm** it displays the project name before my prompt, as in the picture below.

The project name disappears when I source my `.zshrc` file.

[Pic of command line prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Suz2h.png)

I am using oh-my-zsh. I have gone through my `.zshrc` commenting out each line to discover what makes the difference. It turns out it is `ZSH_THEME="agnoster"`.

When I remove this line I can source my `.zshrc` multiple times, but the project name remains at the start of the prompt.

When that line is present I only need to source it once. I always need to source it in the terminal window to get rid of it. Duplicating that line in the `.zshrc` doesn't make a difference.

What is strange about this is that the theme is loading when the terminal window opens for the first time, as you can see in the screenshot. This tells me that the file is being sourced accurately. For some reason I need to source it again to get rid of the project name.

I'm on macOS Monterey 12.6.

**(2022.3.2 (Community Edition), Build #PC-223.8617.48, built on January 24, 2023)

Comment: Are you using virtualenv or conda or something like that in pycharm? That looks like one of those tools is activating an environment and adding the environment name to the prompt variable. It can usually be disabled with an environment variable or a config file somewhere